# Failed to convert Jbehave named parameters without delemeters

Tags: jbehave, serenity-bdd

We are using Serenity with Jbehave for out automation stories, and we have recently upgraded our version to Serenity(2.2.1) and jbejave(1.46.0). Jbehave-core updated from 4.1.3 to 4.4. After the update i am facing an issue with examples table. it is forcing to use delimiter for the step table provided which is taken from story Examples.
This worked previously and got expected values into table

```
Scenario: Verify scenario
Meta:
Given modal should contains the next content:
{transformer=FROM_LANDSCAPE}
| modalTitle       | expectedTitle1      |
| modalFooterTitle | expectedFooterTitle | 
Examples:
{transformer=FROM_LANDSCAPE}
| expectedTitle1      | this is first expected title |
| expectedFooterTitle | This is expected footer text |
```

Now i have to use delimiter to get my expected content into table as below

```
Given product modal should contains the next content:
{transformer=FROM_LANDSCAPE}
| modalTitle       | <expectedTitle1>      |
| modalFooterTitle | <expectedFooterTitle> |
Examples:
{transformer=FROM_LANDSCAPE}
| expectedTitle1      | this is first expected title |
| expectedFooterTitle | This is expected footer text |
```

Also tried with configuration steps like `ParameterControls().useDelimiterNamedParameters(false)` but didn't worked. We have already implemented thousands of stories and it is hard to replace storied with delimiters. is there any work around to solve my problem?